# Build multiple artifacts with different classifiers at once

Tags: maven, maven-3

W want my maven project to produce three artifacts with different classifiers at once. I know that I can produce it with modules etc. This is actually a resources project that I want to produce configuration for DEV, STAGE and PROD environment.

What I want to have is to run `mvn:install` once and have `my.group:resources:1.0:dev`, `my.group:resources:1.0:stage` and `my.group:resources:1.0:prod` in my repo.

Comment: Not a dupe but a *very* similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866784/release-different-configurations-with-maven

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done without profiles if you specify multiple plugin executions and [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files).

Create a properties file for each version in `${basedir}/src/main/filters` (e.g. prod.properties, dev.properties) holding appropriate values for each environment.

Turn on filtering for your resources:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Now add the resource plugin executions.  Note the different filter file and output directory.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-resources</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/dev</outputDirectory>
        <filters>
          <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/dev.properties</filter>
        </filters>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>prod</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/prod</outputDirectory>
        <filters>
          <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/prod.properties</filter>
        </filters>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Finally, the jar plugin; note classifier and input directory:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-jar</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>dev</classifier>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/dev</classesDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>jar-prod</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>prod</classifier>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/prod</classesDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running `mvn clean install` should produce the properly filtered resources in artifacts with `dev` and `prod` classifiers like you want.

In the example, I used execution IDs of `default-resources` and `default-jar` for the dev versions.  Without this you would also get an unclassified jar artifact when you build.

Comment: In the packages are included **prod.properties** and **dev.properties**, how do I do if I want both jar files to have the same, let's say, **config.properties?**

Comment: @ChristianVielma, are you asking about including config.properties in your jars or using config.properties as filters for both jars?

Comment: I mean what if I have a config-dev.properties and a config-prod.properties, how do I do to have only one config.properties in each of the generated jars. Do I explain myself?

Comment: In my answer, the prod.props and dev.props files are filters, not configuration.  You could put config.properties in /src/main/resources, values in there would be filled in during the filtering, and you end up with one file in the final artifact.  If this isn't quite enough, you should probably ask a separate question describing what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: This doesn't includes the libraries. And in my case it didn't even include the classes of my application.

Comment: Please note that the original question specifically mentioned a resources project; the OP's intent was to create classified jars containing resources specific to a particular environment, not classes, libs, etc.  The answer satisfies the given requirement.  Adapt the pattern to fit your requirements if they are different.  Or consider writing a custom plugin.

Comment: Here is simialr solution, but for WARs
http://www.jayway.com/2010/01/21/one-artifact-with-multiple-configurations-in-maven/

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI - put the version number in there to make sure you have the version supporting custom filters. In maven 3 I set mine up like this for example. Without version it didn't work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```