# Avoid Maven profiles to generate duplicated jars

Tags: java, maven

**I'm new to Maven and I'm trying to configure Maven to generate 2 jars: one for development and one for production**. The only difference between them is a config.properties file that have the database connection different so I thought I could use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html).

To my surprise **I can't generate both files at once**. When using profiles, each time you build you have to select the profile and a jar (in my case) will be created using the profile. The thing is that it will create 2 exactly equals jars, one without a classifier and one with the classifier (**like myjar.jar and myjar-prod.jar**) so if I want to generate the dev and the prod jar I have to create 4 jars (running first Maven with one profile and after that with another profile)

**Why is this?** *Doesn't make any sense to me... but ok...*

**My question is:**

**Is there a way I could avoid the two jars from being generated?** I mean, I want to have different profiles, and I have accepted (with grief) to execute multiple times the build process (one for each profile), **could I avoid to have each time 2 jars and have only one without the classifier?**

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.p2p.</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoadACHFiles</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>          
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>        
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>config-*.properties</exclude>          
                </excludes>
            </resource>      
        </resources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
             <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>                                    
                                    <tasks>
                                        <!--<delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>-->
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/config-prod.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.13</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <classifier>prod</classifier>
                                    <source>1.6</source>
                                    <target>1.6</target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>        
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: which maven plugin(s) are you using?

Comment: @vikingsteve I added the pom.xml for reference

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with having classified jars, you may do what you want without profiles, so you may have jars for all environments with a single build command.  The key is to understand how [Maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) works.

This is expanding on an answer I provided to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321395/944849).  Start with that setup.  Then:

Create `config.properties` in your `src/main/resources`, containing properties your app needs.

```
my.database.url=${database.url}
my.database.user=${database.user}
my.database.pw=${database.pw}
```

Now, create `prod.properties` and `dev.properties` in `${basedir}/src/main/filters` holding appropriate values for each environment.

```
database.url=URL-for-dev
database.user=user-for-dev
database.pw=pw-for-dev
```

When you run `mvn clean package`, Maven will copy the contents of `/src/main/resources`, including `config.properties`, doing property replacement during the copy.  Because there are multiple executions of both resources and jar plugins, Maven will create separate classified jar files.  Each will contain a `config.properties` file, holding the correct properties for the environment.  The filters will not end up in the built jars.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: This almost did the trick, but the classes aren't packaged. I'm also using the maven-assembly-plugin in order to create the jar with all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I made it removing the maven jar plugin in the profile section. Changed this:

```
<profile>
        <id>prod</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>                                    
                                <tasks>
                                    <!--<delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>-->
                                    <copy file="src/main/resources/config-prod.properties"
                                          tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>prod</classifier>
                                <source>1.6</source>
                                <target>1.6</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

For this:

```
<profile>
        <id>prod</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>                                    
                                <tasks>
                                    <!--<delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>-->
                                    <copy file="src/main/resources/config-prod.properties"
                                          tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.properties"/>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>               
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: If you don't use a classifier, how do you know if the artifact in the repository was created for prod or dev?

Comment: I have to check the jar file before deploying. Is not the best solution, but couldn´t find any other, and this seems to solve my problem.