# Build artifacts with different classifiers

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

My Maven project is a jar that's going to be used in both Java 6 and Java 7 projects.
So I'd like to have different artifacts that could be used like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>jdk6</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I also want them to be built in one pass. So profiles are probably not the way to go.
I tried using multiple plugin executions.

First, I create two separate build directories:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>createClassesDir</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/jdk6" />
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/jdk7" />
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I try to configure maven-compiler-plugin to build twice, in the two directories:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jdk6</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <d>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jdk6</d>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jdk7</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <d>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jdk7</d>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I can't get it to work. It never compiles the second time, because the source files were already compiled:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ example ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to [...]/example/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (jdk6) @ example ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (jdk7) @ example ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

Do you know how I could compile for both environments?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320322/build-multiple-artifacts-with-different-classifiers-at-once

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, because that other question is related to having different resources, while this one is about compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Let be very honest you should not be creating two maven jars from the same maven project. 
There is a reason behind it that you can read [here](http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/).

The same article also explains two ways in which you can still do it, if you want to

```
    Using profiles
    By doing two executions of maven jar plugin
```

You can also refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets) on SO.

Further more if you don't have any problems having two pom files for your project, you can achieve the same by having 2 pom files ,something like this and build them seprately.

```
  pom-jdk6.xml
  pom-jdk7.xml
```