# Create multiple profile jars using Maven

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I have a Maven project with a single POM. I have multiple profiles and two profile specific properties files.

I want to create multiple jar files, one for each profile id. To this loadable jar, I need to add the profile specific property file.
The jars should NOT have all the dependencies, just all the class files so that each of the jars can be made as dependencies in other Maven projects.

Questions:

1. Has anyone done this before and can this be done in Maven or do I need to use the antrun builder?
2. If it can be done what is the best combination of Maven plugins to use?
3. I am generating the properties files whose names have a profile id extension, these names have to be changed to a default name before adding it to the jar.
4. It seems to be easy to do one or the other .... just the jar or just the properties file ... but generating the specific jar with the specific properties file is the greatest pain.

Any example POM xml would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to do this with multiple plugin executions as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12321395/944849).

Comment: You need having different dependencies you need to make separate modules off it. And a profile is the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one way of doing it is through Maven assemblies.

The structure:

```
multi-profile
|
+-- pom.xml
+-- profile-1.properties
+-- profile-2.properties
+-- src 
    |
    +-- assembly
    |   |
    |   +-- profile-1.xml
    |   +-- profile-2.xml
    |
    +-- main
        |
        +-- java
            |
            + ...
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>multi-profile</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>multi-profile</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>create-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-1</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/profile-1.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-2</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/profile-2.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-3</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/profile-1.xml</descriptor>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/profile-2.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
</project>
```

One assembly (`profile-1.xml`, the other one is very similar):

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>profile-1</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <files>
      <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/profile-1.properties</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <destName>config.properties</destName>
      </file>
    </files>
    <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
        <!-- This will exclude any transitive dependencies from being included in your assembly -->
        <includes>
          <include>org.example:multi-profile</include>
        </includes>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
      </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

If you run `mvn clean install` then no properties file will be included. If you run `mvn -P profile-3 clean install` will create all profiles (in separate artifacts) in one single build. The assembly will rename the properties file as you wanted (to `config.properties` in this case).

If some other project need one of these "profile builds" as a dependency, simply refer to it like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>multi-profile</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>profile-1</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Hope it works for you.