# Property File Processing during build time

Tags: maven, properties, build, maven-plugin, file-processing

My requirments are as follow :
 - we are having four environments(dev,uat,prod,stag)
 - currently we are having 5 property files(log4j.properties for example) one for each 
   environment like : log4j_dev.properties, log4j_uat.properties, log4j_prod.properties,      log4j_stag.properties
 - all the above files have most of the things in common, just some 4 to 5 properties are different in each file.

my current requirments is that we have to put all the properites in a common file(log4j.properties for example ) and the environment specific file would contain only 
the specific 4 to 5 property . during build time these files should be merged and a new file should be created containing all these properties .

I tried [maven-config-processor-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/) thats working fine with mavne 2 , but its not compatible with maven3 . Currently we are using maven3 so i need some alternative approach .
Is there any alternative to maven config-processor or i need to write some new maven plugin for doing so .

Any suggestions plz .

Comment: As far as I can see at [the plugin's site](http://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/) - it is Maven 3 compatible. Can you explain where is the incompatibility problem?

Comment: If your requirement is to embed specific config files inside the war, you might try multiple executions for the war plugin, this creates war artifacts with a helpful suffix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866784/release-different-configurations-with-maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use maven-resources-plugin and the filtering option on resources

Here is an example :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/${target.filter}.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <resources>          
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>              
        </configuration>            
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you have a directory src/main/filters. For each of your environment you add a filter_env.properties.
In it, you put your key you want to variabilize, like this

```
ys.client.service.port=8511
ys.client.service.url=http://localhost/yoda-client/service/yoda
ys.env=dev
```

And finally, in your properties file, you add variables instead of real values. The plugin will replace values with the filters ones :

```
ys.client.service.port=${ys.client.service.port}
ys.client.service.url=${ys.client.service.url}
ys.environment=${ys.env}
```

Comment: thanx yodamad it is really helpfull for me